# Subsetting rows and columns with given indices

Tags: r, indexing

I wish to subset a matrix/ data.frame with a set of indices that I have. For instance if I do:

```
a=matrix(1:20,4)
a[1:2,1:2]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    5
[2,]    2    6
```

However, I was hoping to only get a[1,1] and a[2,2] only. How can you do this in R without using a for loop.

Comment: `a[rbind(c(1, 1), c(2, 2))]`

Comment: Do you want to put this as an answer so I can mark as solved?

Comment: Looks like @thelatemail found it answered already.